# function executes after call

Tags: swift, function, swift3

I am just new to the Swift language and into coding. I have created a function that can *call on mobile number* and created a function that can send text SMS. after the call function is finished the sendJSON will execute.
Can someone help me. Thanks

**Call Function**

```
func call() {
    if let telephoneURL = URL(string: "tel://\(dispatchNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: ""))") { //Calling on the phone
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(telephoneURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(telephoneURL)
            }
        }
    }
```

**SendSMS Function**

```
func sendJSON() {
let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

if(MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText())
{
    messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self
    messageVC.body = "test"
    messageVC.recipients = "123456789"

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use completionHandler for this

```
func call() {
    if let telephoneURL = URL(string: "tel://\(dispatchNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: ""))") { //Calling on the phone
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(telephoneURL, options: [:], completionHandler: {[weak seld] in
                self?.sendJSON()
                })
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(telephoneURL)
        }
    }
}
```